# Source a script to return calculation over input values of a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Me and my team are building a shiny app based on financial research over european sme's. The app includes a series of calculation over user inputs and the code is becoming rather big.

We are new to shiny but where looking to a way to source calculations to external scripts. We already use scripts for data import and functions but in a nutshell what we were looking was for something that would something like this:

```
    script_add:add <- function(x,y){ x + y } 
    ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("user_x"),
    textInput("user_y")
    verbatimTextOutpu(outputId = "result")     
)

    Server <- function(input,output){
    #assume script is on the working folder
    results <- source(file = "script_add", x = input$user_x, y = "user_y")

#renders results    
output$result <- renderPrint({
results
})
}
```

Any one has any ideas on this matter?

Comment: You can place functions in external files and source them, see https://www.r-bloggers.com/storing-a-function-in-a-separate-file-in-r/ Note that when you deploy the app, the function source files must be uploaded with the server and ui

Comment: Yeah we are already using source() to define externally some functions. We end up deciding to just define more complex functions on each script in order to reduce the main code on the app ui and server file. Thanks for your help